# Check card in AppleWallet

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible to get the list of cards, connected to Apple Wallet? Or check if card connected to AppleWallet?

Stripes API has this feature. But is there a native way to implement this task?

I found [developer.apple.com/apple-pay/get-started](https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/get-started/) - Card verification but no word if PassKit supports it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get to know that platform detects on backend added cards to AppleWallet. So all keys and sorted logic is not part of the client

Comment: Very strange and unusual behavior for Apple(